# scikitlearn breaks pandas installation

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I have a problem having pandas and sklearn work together. Importing any module from sklearn, makes pandas run havoc.

This is a minimal example of my problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pandas as pd
import sklearn.metrics as sk

df_train = pd.DataFrame()
print df_train
```

Which prints:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/config.py:570: DeprecationWarning: height has been deprecated.

 warnings.warn(d.msg, DeprecationWarning)
```

If I comment the line where I import `sklearn.metrics`, everything works correctly

Help? :}

Jose

Comment: this is fixed for 0.13 (coming soon), but is just a warning in any event

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can ignore the warning message with:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning,
                        module="pandas", lineno=570)
```

which should be safe for now. As @Jeff notes, it'll be fixed in pandas 0.13.